# How to disable All JSF images from JSF/ADF components?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I wonder if there is a way to disable the rendering of all images from all JSF components. As you know, JSF/ADF components have thier own builtin images, which is really nice but I have a weird requirement to not displaying those images at all.

I am using JSF and ADF Faces (not ADF Rich Faces). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that none of the standard JSF components use any images, so the ones you are seeing must come from ADF.  Check their documentation.  Hopefully they have a plain stylesheet you can choose. Richfaces has that as an option.

Comment: Yes, I used ADF components, so how would I disable them?